# Form validation in jsp page using JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i am using jsp for registration form. I use servlet for verification of existing username. how can i write client side validation code in javasript.
My registration form is

```
<form action="Registration" method="post" name="registration" >
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>:<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name"    
class="input_Name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Place</td>
    <td>:<input type="text" name="place" value="" placeholder="Place"    
class="input_Place"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>:<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender">Male
    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender">Female</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>UserName</td>
    <td>:<input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="UserName" 
  class="input_UserName"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" 
 class="input_Password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Confirm sword</td>
    <td>:<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="re-
 Password" class="input_re-Password"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" ></td>
</tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

one way to deal with that is this code:

```
<td>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick='validate()'>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var val = registration.password.value;
        if (val == null || val.trim() == "") {
            alert('Please enter password.');
            registration.password.focus();
            return false; // cancel submission
        } else {
            document.registration.submit(); // allow submit
        }
    }
</script>
```

if the password field has a value the submit will be executed, otherwise it will be canceled and the focus is set to the password field.

Comment: But My form have action property. when am click submitt button   it goes to the servlet for verifying if the username is existing or not. before goes to the server i want check the required field validation, confirm validation...

Comment: thats the reason for the onClick='validate()' method for your submit button. that will be executed before the request is started to the server.

Answer (score -1):

> Below you use javascript add ID to html input tag. You need to use
>   AJAX to do verification from client Side.

Below code may help you

FUNCTION_URL : Your server side method to verify username availability

```
var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();

$.get(FUNCTION_URL,{username : username,
                    password : password}{
   if(data.status){
       console.log("Username available");
   }else{
       console.log("Username Unavailable");
   }
});
```